# Наложить один DataFrame на другой по Datetime

Tags: python, pandas

В первом датафрейме у меня значения с интервалом раз в минуту

```c#
DateTime1             Value1
2021-01-15 17:19:00   73.681
2021-01-15 17:20:00   73.694
2021-01-15 17:21:00   73.704
2021-01-15 17:22:00   73.708
```

Во втором значения располагаются в другое время с точностью до секунды

```c#
DateTime2             Value2
2021-01-15 17:20:11   73.6768
2021-01-15 17:20:16   73.6767
2021-01-15 17:20:58   73.6700
2021-01-15 17:21:01   73.6584
2021-01-15 17:21:08   73.6614
```

Я бы хотел их наложить по дате, чтобы в итоговом датафрейме были и `Value1` и `Value2` по типу:

```c#
DateTime              Value1  Value2
2021-01-15 17:19:00   73.681  NaN
2021-01-15 17:20:00   73.694  NaN
2021-01-15 17:20:11   NaN     73.6768
2021-01-15 17:20:16   NaN     73.6767
2021-01-15 17:20:58   NaN     73.6700
2021-01-15 17:21:00   73.704  NaN
2021-01-15 17:21:01   NaN     73.6584
2021-01-15 17:21:08   NaN     73.6614
2021-01-15 17:22:00   73.708  NaN
```

Я пробовал `.join` и  `.merge`, но они либо исключали значения первого, которые не включены во второе, либо добавляли значения второго датафрейма в конец первого, а я бы хотел их именно наложить друг на друга

[Пример данных](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/4SSXoFnrbHixvw)

Comment: Вы бы хотя бы части исходных датафреймов привели в вопросе.

Comment: @strawdog так вроде привел же

Comment: нет, не привели. ваши примеры не показательны. если я захочу разобраться  в вашем вопросе, мне  с какими данными работать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще ваша задача решается простым `merge`, если я правильно понял вопрос.
при ваших данных делаем просто

```py
df1=pd.read_csv("Values1.csv", sep=";", index_col=0, parse_dates=["DateTime1"])
df2=pd.read_csv("Values2.csv", sep=";", index_col=0, parse_dates=["DateTime2"])

res = pd.merge(df1,df2, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

получаем res:

```c#
                     Value1   Value2
2021-01-15 17:19:00  73.681      NaN
2021-01-15 17:20:00  73.694      NaN
2021-01-15 17:20:11     NaN  73.6768
2021-01-15 17:20:16     NaN  73.6767
2021-01-15 17:20:21     NaN  73.6807
2021-01-15 17:20:25     NaN  73.6759
2021-01-15 17:20:30     NaN  73.6794
2021-01-15 17:20:35     NaN  73.6765
2021-01-15 17:20:41     NaN  73.6654
2021-01-15 17:20:47     NaN  73.6650
2021-01-15 17:20:53     NaN  73.6725
2021-01-15 17:20:58     NaN  73.6700
2021-01-15 17:21:00  73.704      NaN
2021-01-15 17:21:01     NaN  73.6584
2021-01-15 17:21:08     NaN  73.6614
2021-01-15 17:22:00  73.708      NaN
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Добавил образец данных в конец поста, будьте добры, попробуйте с теми данными. Ваш пример у меня немного некорректно замержил

Comment: я обновил ответ для ваших исходных. проверьте.